# .htaccess not working in xampp (Windows 10)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I created .htaccess file on my xampp apache server.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^zaloguj$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^utworz-konto$ register.php [L]
```

And it works until i add

```
ErrorDocument 404 err404.html
```

Then it shows error 500. I tried to check httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/XAMPP/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And for me it looks like it should work. RewriteRules are only thing that work without creating error 500.

Comment: have you mod_rewrite module on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs point out: [Custom Error Responses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

> ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"
>   ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover
>   ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
>   ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html
>   ErrorDocument 401 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html

The syntax of the ErrorDocument directive is:

```
ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>
```

where the action will be treated as:

- A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").
- An external URL to redirect to (if the action is a valid URL).
- Text to be displayed (if none of the above). The text must be wrapped in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word.

---

These being said, your directive: `ErrorDocument 404 err404.html`
 does not match a local url.

Use `/err404.html` if the page is in the document root, otherwise use the full path, but either way, start with a `/`